# Transform a link, depending on user agent string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use Knack, an online database platform, it works well.

However, I have a use case where I need to take the contents of a cell, in this case 01433443665, and then transform that number into a URL containing that number and then present browser 1 with a URL which looks like

```
http://192.168.1.50/callr.php?01433443665
```

and browser 1 with a URL which looks like

```
http://192.168.1.50/calll.php?01433443665
```

If you're wondering what on Earth this is for, it's to allow the database cell to be clicked and then Asterisk (at 192.168.1.50) takes the number and dials it on the user's deskphone.

Browser 1 is in one room, Browser 2 in another. They have separate extensions and separate deskphones.

This would have to be done with Jquery/Javascript.

I currently use Javascript like the below:

```
$(document).on("db-view-render.view_321", function (event, view, data) {
  $("input#field_32").keyup(function() { 
    var str=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/gi,"");
    var d1=(str.length<=10)?str.toUpperCase():str.slice(0,11).toUpperCase();    
    $("#field_32").attr("value",d1); 
  });
});
```

to enforce only numbers in an input field in the database. It works well.

I'm guessing I'd have to use a Chrome extension like [Custom User Agent](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-useragent-string/lejiafennghcpgmbpiodgofeklkpahoe?hl=en) to allow the two browsers to identify themselves to the javascript...but how to tie this all up and make it work is totally beyond me. I understand the theory and steps needed (I think) but can't begin to imagine how to code for it.

Any help much appreciated!!

Thanks...

Comment: Really hard to understand what is your problem. Cookies?

Comment: Sorry. Cookies is an approach I hadn't considered and is probably a miles better way of doing it than user agent string now you mention it!

So basically I want to use Jquery to transform (e.g.) 01433443665 to either http://192.168.1.50/calll.php?01433443665 or http://192.168.1.50/callr.php?01433443665 depending on the cookie installed on the machine. I don't know how to do this :-( I realise this is quite an ask!